# Div is not opening below particular ngFor in Angular 6

Tags: accordion, angular6, ngfor

I am iterating ngFor in angular 6. When i am clicking on button a div should open beside row of that particular button but it is opening below ngFor [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsujQ.png)
I want to make it open for that partcular row and below that.

```
<app-filter></app-filter>

<div class="bg-white" *ngFor="let data of dashboardData">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="center-align row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="block col-sm-2">
                    {{data.firstname}}{{data.lastname}}
                </div>
                <div class="block_l col-sm-3">
                    <span class="light_small">68%</span>
                    {{data.stage}}
                </div>
                <div class="block_l col-sm-1">
                    Customer
                </div>
                <div class="block_l col-sm-1">
                    <img src="assets/images/call.png">
                </div>
                <div class="block_l col-sm-1">
                    <img src="assets/images/mail.png">
                </div>
                <div class="block_l col-sm-2">
                    <span class="status_color"><b>.</b></span>
                    Paused
                </div>
                <div class="block_l col-sm-2">
                    <a class="btn button_css" (click)="openLayout=!openLayout">verify Details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-loader"></div>
    <div class="container" [hidden]="openLayout">
        <div class="row">
            <app-form-layout></app-form-layout>
            <app-form-desc></app-form-desc>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Now it is coming like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc2uh.png)

[Desired behavior will be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2n64.png) It's like accordian on click it should open below that row and rest of below rows will be shifted downwards

Comment: please post your template complete of ngFor

Comment: @firegloves I have edited question. Please go through complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resides into `openLayout` variable that is shared for all your rows.
You need one `openLayout` for each row. you can add it dinamically to your `data` like this:

```
<div class="bg-white" *ngFor="let data of dashboardData">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="center-align row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="block col-sm-2">
                    {{data.firstname}}{{data.lastname}}
                </div>
                <div class="block_l col-sm-3">
                    <span class="light_small">68%</span>
                    {{data.stage}}
                </div>
                <div class="block_l col-sm-1">
                    Customer
                </div>
                <div class="block_l col-sm-1">
                    <img src="assets/images/call.png">
                </div>
                <div class="block_l col-sm-1">
                    <img src="assets/images/mail.png">
                </div>
                <div class="block_l col-sm-2">
                    <span class="status_color"><b>.</b></span>
                    Paused
                </div>
                <div class="block_l col-sm-2">
                    <a class="btn button_css" (click)="data.openLayout=!data.openLayout">verify Details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-loader"></div>
    <div class="container" [hidden]="data.openLayout">
        <div class="row">
            <app-form-layout></app-form-layout>
            <app-form-desc></app-form-desc>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the beginning it will be false because undefined is like false.

Comment: Now the hidden div is hiding behind ngFor loop. Not coming for each div particularly

Comment: i'm not understanding what you are trying to do

Comment: I have added screenshot in edited question. Hidden div is opening below ngFor.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the desired behaviour please?

Comment: it seems a css problem, have you checked with developer tools inspection if all the elements are at their place?